# Rendering animation on mobile via JavaScript class or CSS change not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, animation

Why is that when i'm trying to add a Class via JavaScript to an element or change CSS from `opacity:0;` to `opacity:1;` - it just doesn't work. BUt when i changed it from `opacity:0.0000001;` to `opacity:1;` - everything works just fine.

Same was with changing scale from `transform:scale(0)` to `transform:scale(1)` but in this case i needed to make at least: `transform:scale(0.1)` so element was visible. Otherwise it didn't worked.

But when i resized/rotated the phone or make some changes inside the DOM - it showed up.

It's happening on this website when i'm opening it in Android Chrome:
https://killthevirus.vot.pl - it's currently working but as you can see opacity of `.the-end` element is natively set to: `0.000001` it doesn't work when it's `0`

What kind of sorcerry is this?

Comment: show the CSS, I think I know why - the transition needs to exist before changing the value being transitioned - you can't add a transition and the new value at the same time

Comment: Please add a text-based [mcve] showing what you're seeing?

Comment: added a link to a website @JaromandaX - it's not that - transition is already inside a class. Anyway - even without transition it should still work and change the value from 0 - 1.

Comment: `transition is already inside a class` the one you're adding? `even without transition it should still work` depending on specificity of course - you've shown absolutely NOTHING regarding any code, just a couple of style  properties, with no selectors